# Use jquery to set focus on a field prior to a link

Tags: jquery, forms, datepicker

I have several date fields that I am using with pickadate.js.  When you focus the field, the date picker pops up. Works great.

The client wants a graphic icon next to each field which should set the focus to the field (and therefore pop up the picker), like this:

[image: picker]

My code for each field is like this:

```
<div class="date-picker">
    <label for="start-date">Start Date</label>
    <input id="start-date" class="datepicker" type="text" readonly="">
    <div class="date-button"><img src="/images/icon-datefield.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

I have tried some things like this, but to no avail:

```
$('.date-button').click(function(){
    $(this).prev().focus();
})
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$(this).prev().focus();
```

Try to get the elem by `.siblings()` method and fire the `.focus()` event to that:

```
$(this).siblings('input').focus();
```

---

As per your latest comment:

```
$('.date-button').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings(".datepicker").datepicker().focus();
});
```

Here you have to initialize the datepicker too.

#### [FIND THIS IN FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bNKdW/)

Comment: This does indeed put the focus on the field, but unfortunately does not activate pickadate. I tried click as suggested by @jibran-khan but that doesn't fire it either. I even tried `$(this).siblings('input').pickadate();` that does nothing at all.

Comment: @Steve just added an other solution to this.

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  Perhaps I will just use Jquery UI instead.  

If anyone finds this and is interested in doing it with datepicker.js, I think I have it working now with its API. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.date-button').click(function(){
$(this).prev().click();
})
```

Comment: Thanks.  See my comment below: this does it fact highlight the field like it was clicked on but doesn't activate the plugin like a "real" click.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are better for solving it, using a jquery UI datepicker, but in case anyone wants to use the [datepicker.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/), this finally worked:

```
var start_date_open = $( '#start-date' ).pickadate(),
    start_calendar_open = start_date_open.data( 'pickadate' ),
    start_button_open = $( '.date-button' ).on({
                    click: function() {
                        setTimeout( function() {
                            start_calendar_open.open()
                        }, 0)
                    }
                });
```